# Can an escape attempt be made when using an attack power which lets you move as part of it?

Tags: dnd-4e

Escaping a grab requires a move action as defined in the rules.

> You attempt to escape from an enemy
>   who has grabbed you (see “Grab”).
>   Other immobilizing effects might let
>   you make escape attempts.
>
> ESCAPE: MOVE ACTION

If a power allows the character to move as part of an attack, can that movement be used to attempt an escape?

As always, concrete references or supporting logic preferred over personal opinions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

Let's take a look at the grabbed and immobilized conditions.

> **Grabbed**
>
> Being grabbed means a creature is immobilized. Maintaining this condition on the creature occupies whatever appendage, object, or effect the grabber used to initiate the grab. This condition ends immediately on the creature if the grabber is subjected to an effect that prevents it from taking actions, or if the creature ends up outside the range of the grabbing power or effect.
>
> **Immobilized**
>
> When a creature is immobilized, it can’t move, unless it teleports or is pulled, pushed, or slid.

Being immobilized means you cannot move of your own will. So if an attack power allows you to *move* or *shift*, you are unable to do so. If the power says you can *teleport*, you are able to. And that will break the grab.

There is nothing special about the immobilized condition in this case, it is what it is regardless of it being from a grab or from some other source.  The only special rule here is for escaping a grab, which allows the target to end the immobilized condition using a move action - Escape.

To reiterate, escaping is a move action, but that doesn't mean that it can be done as part of another move.  It just means it takes up your move action out of the normal standard, move, minor you are allotted with each round.

> **Escape**: Move Action
>
> Acrobatics or Athletics: Make an Acrobatics check vs. Reflex or an Athletics check vs. Fortitude against
>   the creature or effect that immobilized you.
>   
>   Success: You end the grab and can shift as part of this move action.
>   Failure: You’re still grabbed.

So once you've attempted an Escape, you've used your move action. If you succeeded, great, you can shift one square and are free to continue your turn. If not, you can try again by sacrificing your standard action for another move.

The only way to use a movement power to break a grab is if the *grabbing* creature is moved.  If they are moved further away from their grabbed target than they can reach, the grab ends because they cannot maintain it.

Comment: "Escaping is a move action, but that doesn't mean that it can be done as part of another move." that's the part I'm not certain about. Normally, you can't end the immobilized condition by using a move action. Grabbed is a special case which you can end it by attempting to move. So can that attempt to move be part of another power, is my real question.

Comment: Maybe an easier way to look at it is: Attempting to escape a grab is an explicitly defined `move action`. Moving as a result of an attack power is a `free action` granted by the power.  Now if the attack power said "deal damage and take a move action," that would be different, but there are no powers like that to my knowledge.

Comment: Also, just as a note, you can use your move action while grabbed to get out of the grab, choose not to shift, then use your attack that allows you to move as part of the action to move away the amount the attack states.  If it's not a shift you may draw an AoO but this would be the only way to attack and move out of a grab short of as dpatchery metioned an attack that grants a move action specifically or an attack that pushes before granting a move (thus breaking the grab before the move).

Comment: Just to add DPatchery for power examples similar to what you were mentioning about "deal damage and take a move action", the Rogue's Level 13 encounter power Tornado Strike does deal damage and then move while also forcing up to the 2 targets (assuming both are hit) to be pushed away.  Not sure if that was what you were referring to.